# App router: top level dynamic route is being triggered on _next folder, assets, devtools, etc

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I have the following folder structure: `app/[gameType]/[[...gameId]]`

It appears that having a top level dynamic route like that causes havoc in NextJs with the app router. I tried to restrict the dynamic route, but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Here is `app/[gameType]/[[...gameId]]/page.tsx`:

```
'use server';

import type { GameId } from '@/types';
import { GameType } from '@/types'; // this is an Enum

export async function generateStaticParams() {
    const validGameTypes = Object.values(GameType);
    return validGameTypes.map((gameType) => ({ gameType }));
}

export default async function GameDirector({ params }: { params: { gameType: GameType, gameId?: GameId[] } }) {
    const { gameType } = params;
    const gameId = params.gameId?.[0];
    // ... rest of file
}
```

I'm finding that `gameType` sometimes has values like `_next` or `gameId` is  `react_devtools_backend_compact.js.map`, and this is causing exceptions to be thrown from my code. Best I can tell, that generateStaticParams is not doing *anything*.

How can I tell NextJs that `gameType` **must** be in `Object.values(GameType)` or otherwise it should ignore the `[gameType]` dynamic route and treat it like it would if it wasn't dynamic? (i.e. serve `_next` folder normally, give 404 if there wasn't a static route to whatever was being requested). Additionally, gameId is fully dynamic and thus shouldn't be impacted.

Is there a solution to this besides adding another folder level or making the top-level non-dynamic and having a different landing page for each game type even though the code is the same?

Thanks!